# Oracle/PLSQL: BEFORE DELETE TRIGGER error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I have a table named `Members` and a table called `Lapsed_Members` and wish the first to populate the second once a row is deleted. I have created a `BEFORE DELETE TRIGGER` to handle this (Code to follow) and I believe this should work however I receive an error informing me that there is a

> `Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 2`

The trigger, however, doesn't compile:

> `SQL Error: ORA-04098: trigger 'B0025400.LAPSED_MEMBER_TRIGGER'`

Can anyone help me fix this?

Code:

```
CREATE or REPLACE TRIGGER lapsed_member_trigger
BEFORE DELETE
ON Members
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO Lapsed_Members
VALUES
(:old.MemberID,
:old.FirstName,
:old.LastName,
:old.DoB,
:old.MemberType,
:old.GroupID,
:old.HouseNo,
:old.Street,
:old.Town,
:old.County,
:old.PostCode,
:old.LastJoined,
sysdate ); 
END;
```

Additionally, although I'm sure it doesn't matter, I have also tried

```
INSERT INTO Lapsed_Members

(StoredMemberID,
FirstName,
LastName)

VALUES
(:old.MemberID,
:old.FirstName,
:old.LastName);
```

etc...

Script for creation of tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Members(
MemberID number,
FirstName varchar(30),
LastName varchar(30),
DOB date,
MemberType varchar(30),
GroupID number,
HouseNo varchar(30),
Street varchar(30),
Town varchar (30),
County varchar(30),
Postcode varchar(10),
LastJoined date,
constraint Members_PK primary key (MemberID),
constraint Members_FK foreign key (GroupID) references MemberGroups(GroupID)
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE Lapsed_Members(
StoredMemberID number,
FirstName varchar(30),
LastName varchar(30),
DOB date,
MemberType varchar(30),
GroupID number,
HouseNo varchar(30),
Street varchar(30),
Town varchar (30),
County varchar(30),
Postcode varchar(10),
LastJoined date,
LastLeft date,
constraint Lapsed_Members_PK primary key (LapsedMemberID),
constraint Lapsed_Members_FK foreign key (GroupID) references MemberGroups(GroupID));
```

Comment: Are you trying to execute this through Java JDBC call ?

Comment: Apologies I should have made this clearer...

I am using Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: Please edit the question and include the definition of the MEMBERS and LAPSED_MEMBERS table (i.e. the columns on each). Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it's coming from this code - missing parameter errors are run-time, not compile-time. Do you have other statements in your worksheet, and you're running them all as a script, maybe?

Comment: Hi @AlexPoole,

Thanks for the response, it is only the first script that I am trying to run; everything else (tables etc.) already exists.

Comment: Hi @BobJarvis,

I have amended as requested

Comment: [Seems to be fine](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2ea4ff/1), with a correction of `StoredMemberId` to `LapsedMemberID`. So something is missing from the picture.

Comment: thanks again Alex,

what kind of things do you think could be missing from the picture?

as far as I can tell everything is correct but alas it doesn't work

Comment: If I knew that, I'd write an answer *8-) It doesn't make sense to get a run-time parameter error from compilation of a trigger, which has no parameters anyway. Does the trigger exist in `user_triggers`, what status does it have there, and is there anything in `user_errors` for it? It still looks like you're running something else in the same script, after the trigger is (probably successfully) compiled, but you said not. Without being able to see your screen I'm a bit stumped I'm afraid.

Comment: An error such as you're getting seems to indicate a problem in a function or procedure call. Are you calling any functions or procedures?

Comment: @BobJarvis no user created functions or procedures exist.

As for calling them; the code above is the only thing I am trying to run.

Comment: @AlexPoole The trigger does seem to create and does appear in user_trigger and is enabled however when I try and delete a row in 'Member' it doesn't allow me to; due to an error with the trigger: 

SQL Error: ORA-04098: trigger 'B0025400.LAPSED_MEMBER_TRIGGER' is invalid and failed re-validation

Comment: The `status` in `user_objects` will be `INVALID` then; querying `user_errors` will say why it won't compile - hopefully something other than that run-time parameter error?! Since the code you've posted does work there's still something odd happening. Maybe compare what's in `user_source` with what your script has and see if there's anything extra you aren't expecting? (Unless your 'also tried' version is most recent, and `StoredMemberID` is still wrong?)